# Call apply-like function on two rows to match

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a dataframe with multiple rows. I want to call a function is using any two rows. For example, Let's say I have this data and this myFunc which accepts two args:

```
df <- data.frame(q1=c(1,2,5), q2=c(5,5,5), q3=c(5,2,5), q4=c(5,5,5), q5=c(2,3,1))  
df  
   q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  
1   1   5   5   5   2  
2   2   5   2   5   3  
3   5   5   5   5   1  

myFunc<-function(a,b) sum((df[a,]==df[b,] & df[a,]==5)*1)
```

A want to apply myFunc for row 1 and 2, `myFunc(1,2)` and I expect 2, myFunc compute how many "5" are have in common under the same column, between row 1 and 2.

Since I have thousands of rows, and I want to match all pairs, I want do this without writing a for loop, maybe with the do call or apply function family.

I tried this:

```
a=c(1,2)    # match the row 1 and 2    
b=c(2,3)    # match the row 2 and 3    
my_list=list(a,b)

do.call("myFunc", my_list)
```

But I got 4, instead of 2 and 2, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question recently changed.  My understanding of it is that the input should be a list of pairs of row numbers and the output should be the same length as that list such that each component of the output is the number of columns with both entries equal to 5 in both rows defined by the corresponding pair.  Thus for `df` shown in the question the list `L` shown below would correspond to  `c(myFunc(1, 2), myFunc(2, 3))` where `myFunc` is as defined in the question.

```
L <- list(1:2, 2:3)
myFunc2 <- function(x) myFunc(x[1], x[2])
sapply(L, myFunc2)
## [1] 2 2
```

Note that `*1` in `myFunc` is unnecessary since `sum` will coerce a logical argument to numeric.

An alternative might be to specify the first row numbers as a vector and the second row numbers as another vector.  In terms of `L` that would be `a <- sapply(L, "[", 1); b <- sapply(L, "[", 2)`.  Then use `mapply`.

```
a <- c(1, 2)  # L[[1]][1], L[[2]][1]
b <- c(2, 3)  # L[[1]][2], L[[2]][2]
mapply(myFunc, a, b)
## [1] 2 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much you time and tips, however this not works. Only work for a pair, if a have a list or a vector with several  pairs, does not work. This is the main trouble.

Comment: I have modified the answer to correspond to the revisions in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the rows instead of the row index

```
df <- data.frame(q1=c(1,2,5), q2=c(5,5,5), q3=c(5,2,5), q4=c(5,5,5), q5=c(2,3,1))  

myFunc<-function(a,b) sum((a==b & a==5)*1)

myFunc(df[1,],df[2,])
```

This worked for me (returned 2)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the trouble, the function myFunc() works well, the trouble is do in a vector way, to match severals. In this way myFunc(df[1,],df[2,]), if you have several rows to match, like  myFunc(df[1:2,],df[2:3,]), return only one number and not two. Don't work and is not possible to insert in apply function.

Comment: Please clarify by giving an example in the question.

Comment: If you can, please also describe the final objective: why do you want to compare every row?. I often see a better solution than the one the question is trying to fix from this community when the purpose is stated.  For example, if your intent is to find rows that are the most similar, you may find that "k nearest neighbours" (for which packages may exist) is an appropriate solution.

Comment: For the AWaddington tip only work for a pair, if I do with two pairs myFunc(df[1:2,],df[2:3,]), I got number 4, instead 2 an 2